# How to Decide Whether to Buy the Add On or Not in Rebuys

Tags: nlhe, online, tournament, poker-theory

Sometimes rebuy tournaments go very well at the beginning and I accumulate a lot of chips, when I've already got lots of chips it seems silly to pay more money for the add on - usually costing the same as a whole rebuy - to top up my stack by say, less than 20%.

How can I assess whether an add on is worth taking or not?

Is there a generalised threshold something like, if my chip stack is more than 5x the add on, there is no point in purchasing it?

Answer (score 2):

The aim of poker is to have all the chips at the end of the tournament, so the more chips you have at any one time, the better.

If you are one of the chip leaders then don't bother, you already have plenty of chips to boss people about with.

If you are close to the chip lead and the add on is good value then I would probably take it.

If you are low then you should always take it as you need the chips.

On PKR they run a few tournaments where you have more than one stack that you can get at any time for free. I always take them all right at the start and just boss people about. That's why you need as many chips as possible.